# Xcode - Create completely new version of app

Tags: ios, xcode

I have an app that I'd like to completely overhaul from scratch, but keep the settings/app icons and other behind the scene info and preferences. My app isn't much right now but I'd still like to have the option to rollback in case my overhaul doesn't go as well. In essence, I'm not sure how to create some sort of branch that duplicates what I have now so that I can do my overhaul separate from the app in production. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Don't you use version controlling like `git` or something else?

Comment: git GUI like sourcetree is better option for that